# fatal error LNK1169

Tags: c++, fortran, linker-errors, fortran77

The below error list pops up.
I am okay if this had happened on Release build.

It is quite surprising that it has happened in DEBUG build.

> 1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: malloc already defined in libcmt.lib(malloc.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _heap_alloc already defined in libcmt.lib(malloc.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: calloc already defined in libcmt.lib(calloc.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: realloc already defined in libcmt.lib(realloc.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _recalloc already defined in libcmt.lib(realloc.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _expand already defined in libcmt.lib(expand.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: free already defined in libcmt.lib(free.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _msize already defined in libcmt.lib(msize.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_malloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_realloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_recalloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_offset_malloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_offset_realloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_offset_recalloc already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_free already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_msize already defined in libcmt.lib(align.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in libcmt.lib(dbghook.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isctype_l already defined in libcmt.lib(isctype.obj)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isctype already defined in libcmt.lib(isctype.obj)

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're linking to the Debug runtime as well as the Release runtime - probably you have a Release build that links statically to a Debug lib or vice versa.

Comment: YEs Roger..in the list of library dependencies , i was having both the LIBCMT and LIBCMTD.

It worked with release build, as it enconters LIBCMT first.
in case or debug... it failed..

Answer (score 2):

- If your application use any `LIB`s or `DLL`s any of those are statically link with run-time assemblies. that's the  reason for this linking error.
- Run-time assemblies statically liking is not a recommended method
- But if you need to get rid from this linking error here you go, `right-click on project file in project explorer` -> `properties` -> `configuration properties` -> `linker` -> `Input` -> `Ignore Specific Library` -> add `libcmtd.lib`